# Is generated C++ Bison parser re-entrant?

Tags: c++, bison, flex-lexer, reentrancy

I'm working on a hobby project that use flex/bison to generate C++ scanner/parser. Because there are gazillion number of the parsing objects. The parsing itself is embarrassingly parallel problem. I want to pool a couple of ready-to-run scanner/parser object and let them run in parallel.

I read through Flex and Bison official document and skim through their generated codes.

I can confirm that from Flex document and its code the generating C++ scanner is re-entrant.

However, I have hard time to confirm this from Bison document. It does have document stating how to build an re-entrant C parser in Bison. But it doesn't explicitly imply if you build a C++ parser, it is re-entrant. I found a couple of static class member in Bison generated parser header file, which makes me concern on this matter:

```
// Tables.
// YYPACT[STATE-NUM] -- Index in YYTABLE of the portion describing
// STATE-NUM.
static const short int yypact_[];

// YYDEFACT[STATE-NUM] -- Default reduction number in state STATE-NUM.
// Performed when YYTABLE does not specify something else to do.  Zero
// means the default is an error.
static const unsigned char yydefact_[];

// YYPGOTO[NTERM-NUM].
static const signed char yypgoto_[];

// YYDEFGOTO[NTERM-NUM].
static const signed char yydefgoto_[];

// YYTABLE[YYPACT[STATE-NUM]] -- What to do in state STATE-NUM.  If
// positive, shift that token.  If negative, reduce the rule whose
// number is the opposite.  If YYTABLE_NINF, syntax error.
static const short int yytable_[];

static const short int yycheck_[];

// YYSTOS[STATE-NUM] -- The (internal number of the) accessing
// symbol of state STATE-NUM.
static const unsigned char yystos_[];

// YYR1[YYN] -- Symbol number of symbol that rule YYN derives.
static const unsigned char yyr1_[];

// YYR2[YYN] -- Number of symbols on the right hand side of rule YYN.
static const unsigned char yyr2_[];
```

Is generated C++ Bison parser re-entrant?

Answer (score 1):

Those are all `static const` which is totally compatible with reentrancy. The tables define the parser's transition rules and are not fundamentally different from the parser's executable code, which is also static and immutable.

Comment: Very good point! Do you mean the array itself is const or the element of array is const? I need to find a C++ reference to differentiate these.

Comment: C++ arrays (like C arrays) cannot be resized, so there is no difference between the array being const and the array's elements being const.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I reviewed const chapter in C++ Primer. Living in Java world too long, I almost forgot this.